# How to write a C++ routine which checks which key I've pressed on a keyboard so I can handle each key press separately?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I thought several times about this question but I'd always forget to ask. So how can I write a C/C++ routine which checks what key I pressed so the result is returned immediately after the key has been pressed ? How to accomplish that in Windows ? How to accomplish that in Linux ? What headers I should include if I use Dev-C++ and Code::Blocks ?

I try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    using namespace std ;
    cout << "Press a key" << endl ;
    char key ;
    getch() >> key ;
    cout << "\nYou have pressed: " << key << endl ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

but it doesn't tell me what key I pressed. How to get a key value ?

Comment: `How to accomplish that in Windows ? How to accomplish that in Linux ? What headers I should include if I use Dev-C++ and Code::Blocks ?` 
So many questions in a single question?

Comment: code:blocks is an ide

Comment: If this is too many questions, then I need to know only how to accomplish it in windows and Dev-C++ in C++ code

Comment: Are we even talking about console or window-based program?

Comment: I need this in a console program

Comment: I added a code example which doesn't work as I want, so You should now know exactly what I want to attain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getch()` function from `<conio.h>`, for example:

```
int c;
c = getch();
```

There is also a `GetAsyncKeyState` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx you might find useful.

Comment: I don't think that's quite what he's asking. I think he wants a UI which can respond to random keystrokes at arbitrary times. I could be wrong...